# CSS - Dynamic padding to expand divs to fill a dynamic width

Tags: css

So I have a variable number of elements in a div that has a variable width. The elements inside have a fixed space between them, 5px, but each one needs to expand to fill the full width of the space of the outer div with padding, so the text can be centerized.

Example:

```css
.button-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.button-container .button{
  min-width: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
.button-container .button + .button-container .button{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-container'>
  <div class='button'>B1</div>
  <div class='button'>B2</div>
  <div class='button'>B3</div>
  <div class='button'>B4</div>
</div>
```

So how can I make the padding inside of the button class elements have a dynamic left and right padding to fill the space of the button-container class div?

Ideally, the solution will be a CSS only solution, as I don't want to have jQuery to do the spacing.

Comment: So you want the buttons to spread over the full width of the parent, and only adjust the space between those, or you want the buttons to adapt in width?

Comment: The margin is static, but the left and right padding inside the border needs to expand to fill the full width of the button-container.

Comment: In this case, use flexbox. But be aware that this is not supported in older browsers (afaik IE < 10) http://caniuse.com/#search=flex so create a fallback for those browsers. IE10 needs the 2012 version of the flexbox syntax.

Comment: One thing though [**Divs are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: Very good point Paulie_D. They are just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS tables would work here.

```css
.button-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.button-container .button {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-container'>
  <div class='button'>B1</div>
  <div class='button'>B2</div>
  <div class='button'>B3</div>
  <div class='button'>B4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Table-layouting is so far from what I'd usually consider, I would not have had this idea probably even though it's perfectly valid. A good and probably much more compatible solution for this specific problem!

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use an **actual** table but if CSS tables can achieve it (in the absence of full flexbox support) I see it as a valid option. That's why it exists :)

Comment: Agreed. If I could use flexbox, that would probably be my go-to choice, but since I need to support IE9 as well, this will be the solution that I use. Thanks much.

Answer (score 7):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.button-container {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
}
.button-container > .button {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute the width equally */
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
.button-container > .button:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-container'>
  <div class='button'>B1</div>
  <div class='button'>B2</div>
  <div class='button'>B3</div>
  <div class='button'>B4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First time I've heard of the flex attribute. Looks pretty handy. Any way to make it work with IE 7-9?

Comment: @Lianite AFAIK not possible, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though. Will definitely keep this in mind for when we don't have to support older versions of IE anymore.